# Greatest word ocurrencies in 3 files using -Xmx32m java command

Tags: java, algorithm, file, cpu-word, counting

I need to develop an application that retrieves the greatest number of word occurrencies present in 3 files txt, note that all words are sorted ascending inside those files and some words can be present in multiple files. To run the application we shall use the command -Xmx32m (which makes max heap size of 32MB) as example below:

java -Xmx32m greatestNrOccurrencies

I have done the application using hashmap and linked Lists but as soon as i try to use the command -Xmx32m, the application gives an out of memory error. If someone could help with any ideas, i'll be thankfull.

You can find the code below;

```
package topkwordsocurrences;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;

public class TopKWordOcurrences {

    public static void getKWordOcurrences() {
        Scanner firstReader, secondReader, thirdReader;
        Map<String, Integer> uniqueWords = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        String line;
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(".\\src\\topkwordsocurrences\\out.txt");
            firstReader = new Scanner(new FileReader(".\\src\\topkwordsocurrences\\f1.txt"));
            secondReader = new Scanner(new FileReader(".\\src\\topkwordsocurrences\\f2.txt"));
            thirdReader = new Scanner(new FileReader(".\\src\\topkwordsocurrences\\f3.txt"));

            while (firstReader.hasNextLine()) {
                line = firstReader.nextLine();
                
                if (uniqueWords.containsKey(line)) {
                    // if your keys is already in map, increment count of it
                    uniqueWords.put(line, uniqueWords.getOrDefault(line, 0) + 1);
                } else {
                    // if it isn't in it, add it
                    uniqueWords.put(line, 1);
                }
               
            }


            while (secondReader.hasNextLine()) {
                line = secondReader.nextLine();
                
                if (uniqueWords.containsKey(line)) {
                    // if your keys is already in map, increment count of it
                    uniqueWords.put(line, uniqueWords.getOrDefault(line, 0) + 1);
                } else {
                    // if it isn't in it, add it
                    uniqueWords.put(line, 1);
                }
        }

            while (thirdReader.hasNextLine()) {
                line = thirdReader.nextLine();
                if (uniqueWords.containsKey(line)) {
                    // if your keys is already in map, increment count of it
                    uniqueWords.put(line, uniqueWords.getOrDefault(line, 0) + 1);
                } else {
                    // if it isn't in it, add it
                    uniqueWords.put(line, 1);
                }
            }

            //convert HashMap into List
            List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(uniqueWords.entrySet());
            //sorting the list elements in descending order // to make ascending order alter return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
            Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
                public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
                    return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
                }
            });


            List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> top5 = list.subList(0, 5);

            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> i : top5) {
                System.out.println(i.getKey());
            }
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getKWordOcurrences();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that you can do to reduce the memory consumption of your program.

First, you can close each file after reading it. You currently open 3 readers, and do not close them until the program ends. You can do better:

```
String[] fileNames = new String[]{
        ".\\src\\topkwordsocurrences\\f1.txt",
        ".\\src\\topkwordsocurrences\\f2.txt",
        ".\\src\\topkwordsocurrences\\f3.txt"
};
 
for (String fileName : fileNames) {
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            processWord(s.nextLine());
        }
    } // file is closed when this line is reached, even if exceptions thrown
}
```

Note that the above approach also removes a lot of duplication: you only need to implement `processWord` or the logic for opening files once.

You use a `LinkedHashmap` to store words. How many unique words are in your files? If it is normal text, you should have no problem staying within the low memory limit. If words are machine-generated, however, no choice of map will be able to store all of them in memory. In between, other types of map implementation may require less memory - for example, a `HashMap`, while not preserving order, requires somewhat less space per entry than a `LinkedHashmap`. Using a `Scanner` also has an overhead (and it performs read-ahead to improve performance, at a small memory cost). If desperate for memory, using a Reader directly *may* work.

If you have a lot of different words and run out of memory despite making these changes, you can avoid using a hashmap altogether: you are only looking for the *most frequent* word - or the K most-frequent words, so it should be enough to store only *the top K words and their frequencies*.

In pseudocode:

```
open all scanners
for each scanner, 
   count all occurrences of its 1st word
until all scanners are empty:
   sort last-read-words from scanners
   merge counts for the lexicographically smallest word (if found in several scanners)
   check to see if smallest word should enter into top-k list
   for each scanner which had smallest word,
      count occurrences for its next word
```